# How to update bindings inside of a gridview?

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, uwp, c++-cx

I'll use the solution files from here as an example: https://github.com/Windows-Readiness/AbsoluteBeginnersWin10/tree/master/UWP-040/UWP-040 (If the creator has a problem with me linking these for the example, I'll make my own and upload them). Currently, the gridview is bound to a List of a class `book`. One of the properties that the itemtemplate for the gridview binds to is called `Title`. However, if I update Title, and call Bindings.Update(), it will not update it. To illustrate this, I added a button onto the page, and made its actions this:

```
Books[0].Title = "hello";
Bindings.Update();
```

Now when I press the button, what I *want* to have happen is for the first item on the gridview to change it's Title to "hello". However, nothing happens. How do I achieve this behavior? The solution needs to work in C++/CX too, because that's where I'll be using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of `Book` in your sample code is

```
public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string CoverImage { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to update properties in code, you have to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx). Any property changes will then automatically propagate to your UI. Several MVVM frameworks provide a base implementation to make your work easier.

EDIT: as @justanotherxl noticed correctly: `x:Bind` defaults to `OneTime`, for updates this has to changed to `OneWay` (which is the default of regular bindings so those work correctly out of the box).

Comment: Thanks for responding. Does the binding need to be set to Mode=OneWay when using x:Bind with INotifyPropertyChanged? Also, how big is the performance hit when using this? Merry Christmas!

Comment: You're completely correct: regular bindings work out of the box, x:Bind needs to add the OneTime binding. Performance hit for INPC can be neglected.